# Infinitly nested cosines: $\cos(\pi\cos(...))$, what do they look like?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

What does the limit of nested sine or cosine look like?
Does it have any interesting properties or relations with some math research?

It seems to have period doubling, what regions are dense, in the sense that the graph would be completly covered?

[first 4 iterations of nesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r7FS.jpg)

Comment: There are three solutions to $x = \cos(\pi x)$ so if your function is well-defined at $x$, i.e. if it converges when nesting an infinity of times, the function should equal one of these three values. Now it remains to show for which $x$ it converges and to what...

Comment: @Evariste I agree that it looks like the other two solutions are not converging. I would like to point out that there are also points that do not converge and I think when OP asks about the regions that are dense, they are asking about also those values of $x$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Well the solutions have got to be converging at least since $x=\cos(\pi x)$ trivially implies that the function is well-defined at $x$ and yields $x$ so all three solutions are reached by the function, but it seems like most of the other points converge to $-1$. Do you have an example of a point which yields divergence? It's been a long time since I last studied fixed points so my knowledge of them is rusty...

Comment: The image is wrong, I'll correct it when I have time. And see your feed back :)

Comment: @Evariste Let's say $f(x)=\cos(\pi x)$. If you consider the solutions of $f(f(x))=x$ that are not solutions to $f(x)=x$, you will see two solutions that are approximately $x_1=-.297$ and $x_2=.596$. We have that $f(x_1)=x_2$ and vice versa. So $f^n(x_1)$ should not converge as it alternates between two distinct values.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Interesting, thank you. Indeed, for some points OP's function is ill-defined.

Answer (score 2):

As $-1\le \cos(\pi x) \le1,$ we can focus only for $x$ that $-1 \le x \le1$. In this interval the map $\cos(\pi x)$ is [unimodal map](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eartur.avila/survey.pdf) like the [tent map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map) and others well studied maps. In [this paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eartur.avila/survey.pdf) there is many properties of then.

Comment: It doesn't sound right that $\cos(\pi x)$ is conjugate to the tent map -- they have different numbers of fixed points, for one thing.

Comment: You're right, I edit.